# AES encryption (in Java) of different JSON strings always produce same encrypted string as result. Why?

Tags: encryption, aes, java, json

I have a program written in Java which takes JSON string as argument, encrypts it using AES then encodes it using Base64. 
JSON string is like:

```
{"a": "b"} or {"a": "n"} or {"a": "k"}
```

I.e related object would have one property `a`. Value part is randomly generated.

Program outputs for above JSON inputs looks like

```
UBNvKoRoGqk0PTQQL5K4Sw==
bKwlToSND3HkceDExEDXSw==
u/yKJq1FdoifBM+AnadC3A==
```

i.e. they are unique.

Same goes for `{"a":"gn"}` -- random string with length 2. Same for 3 and so on.

But starting from 7 program produces the same encoded string for different inputs. I mean following JSON strings taken as input:

```
{"a": "pzfovvs"}
{"a": "bqwuvck"}
```

produces same string as output:

```
Dwg0Xjkot8UBfn+vbcCfOS4KluXB6RCFQ932Y9ABtIg=
```

Same goes for length 8 and 9. Starting from 10 results became unique again.

What is the explanation of this strange phenomenon?

(I can post code if needed.)

Ok, here is the code:

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;

public class JWTEncryptor {

private static String algorithm = "AES";
private static Key key;
private static KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
private static Cipher cipher;

public static String encrypt(String jwt) throws Exception {
    if (key == null || cipher == null) {
        setUp();
    }
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(jwt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}

private static void setUp() {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (keyGenerator != null) {
        key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        return;
    }
    try {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm);
        key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedJWT) throws Exception {
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    return new 
   String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedJWT)));
} 

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can only be an implementation bug. If the code is not too large, please provide the relevant snippets and we might be able to help. Without the code, there is nothing we can do to debug the problem.

Comment: I agree, an implementation bug.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report for an unspecified program.

Comment: @Demento. You mean bug in AES implementation in Java?

Comment: No, your code is buggy

Comment: Yes, as MechMK1 just said, it is a bug in your code, probably some rather trivial oversight. I don't see anything obvious in the code you provided in the meantime. Might be some issue when calling the encrypt function or printing the result. You should do some step by step debugging and check what happens at every step for your test cases.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment.
I tried the code snippet you gave us, by adding this method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String[] plain = new String[] {
            "{\"a\": \"b\"}",
            "{\"a\": \"n\"}",
            "{\"a\": \"k\"}",
            "{\"a\": \"pzfovvs\"}",
            "{\"a\": \"bqwuvck\"}"
    };
    for (String s : plain) {
        String enc = encrypt(s);
        String dec = decrypt(enc);
        System.out.println(s + "\t" + enc + "\t" + dec);
    }
}
```

And the result is, that I can't reproduce the issue. The output is this:

```
{"a": "b"}  /P80Sou3+dGozWw7eVowRQ==    {"a": "b"}
{"a": "n"}  ht8KPm8KzZE9czjX2Jmu4w==    {"a": "n"}
{"a": "k"}  rFHzmbC3l6zjT4XP6Vhing==    {"a": "k"}
{"a": "pzfovvs"}    RhJi+SasO6tzvLf6yaDTgYhPWMFDIUVaS10zLek43/M=    {"a": "pzfovvs"}
{"a": "bqwuvck"}    S/H0I5qQKT9Fo5zitUzqKohPWMFDIUVaS10zLek43/M=    {"a": "bqwuvck"}
```

It also looks like the implementation is correct.

I used the jdk-13 to test this. So either the Java Version you are using is bugged, or for some reason you don't write the correct `String` to your `encrypt` method and instead are always supplying the same `String`. Eitherway the snippet you have sent works correctly.

Greetings

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Sure it answers the question. It must be an implementation or environment bug, because AES won’t encrypt two different blocks to the same value.

Comment: Thank you very much for testing. The cause of problem was late time of the day and lack of work-life balance. Actually, the JWT strings I am encrypting is much bigger than that I have provided in the question and they are almost the same, so the encrypted result looks the same. With very little difference in the middle of the encrypted string. So, sorry for the trouble.